# Better way to accomplish Nested SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Right now I'm implementing the following sql query for an iphone-app, and I'm using HTTP GET. The SQL query does not contain joins, so is it efficient enough?

```
SELECT
   menu_name 
FROM Menus
WHERE 
  menu_id IN (
    SELECT
      menus_id 
    FROM Restaurants_Menus 
    WHERE Restaurants_id = '$restaurantID'
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Only you can answer if it is efficient *enough*. If it meets your needs, then it is fine. However, it may be faster if you use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  Menus.menu_name
FROM 
  Menus
 JOIN Restaurants_Menus ON Menus.menu_id = Restaurants_Menus.menus_id
WHERE Restaurants_Menus.Restaurants_id = '$restaurantID'
```

You can run them both with `EXPLAIN` to determine where indexes are being used and judge the query execution time.  If `Restaurants_Menus` is not a large table, and `Restaurants_id` is a primary key, the two queries are not likely to differ much in execution time.